# halting problem

Tags: automata

Prove that it is undecidable for the halting problem of a deterministic Turing machine which accepts nonrecursive language

or in-other-words:

let's say we have a deterministic Turing machine which accepts nonrecursive language, prove the halting problem is undecidable

I tried to prove it saying that since it accept nonrecursive language then it must be accepting R.E. languages where it's not guaranteed to be decidable. therefore it's undecidable.

apparently this does not make sense to everyone. please help if you can prove it and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hmm, it seems you're trying to [scoop the loop-snooper](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/loopsnoop.html)

Comment: that is the general idea but I'm trying to be specific in this question

Comment: Ah, whoops. I must have missed the details